# React - how to make properly working computed properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, computed-properties

I am now trying to make table with checkboxes, and got really irritating problem. I reproduced this problem in this example.

I have list of items of format {id, value}. For each item I create div element with checkbox and text inside. When I want to make item selected, I add item id into selectedItems list.
The problem is that I can't make component checkbox update its state on selectedItems list change.

Tell me please, how to do it normally? In Vue, I could just create computed property for each sub-component and pass selectedItems and binded prop. How to do it in React?

```js
import {Checkbox} from "@mui/material";
import {useMemo, useState} from "react";

export default function Example() {
  const items = useState([{id: 0, value: "Item 1"}, {id: 1, value: "Item 2"}, {id: 2, value: "Item 3"}])
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([])
  console.log(items)

  function ListItems({items}) {
    return useMemo(() => {
      const elements = []
      for (let i = 0; i < items[0].length; i++) {
        const item = items[0][i]
        const checked = selectedItems.indexOf(item.id) !== -1
        console.log(item, items.length)
        elements.push(
          <div key={i}>
            <Checkbox
              checked={checked}
              onChange={() => {
                let state = selectedItems
                if (checked) {
                  state = state.filter(id => id !== item.id)
                } else {
                  state.push(item.id)
                }
                setSelectedItems(state)
              }}
            />
            <p>{item.value}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }

      return elements
    }, [items])
  }

  return (
    <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
      <ListItems items={items}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/not-working-computed-props-react-forked-fywtxp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you upload this code somewhere so we can check what is wrong with it 

Comment: Your useMemo is dependent on `items` but not on `selectedItems` so it doesn't re-evaluate, you should do `useMemo(..., [items, selectedItems])` so that if one of `items` or `selectedItems` changes - it re-evaluates

Comment: Yes, you are right. I really missed it this time. But I have to say, that previously I had no useMemo at all, and that didn't affect...

I fixed it now, and it still not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from my comment about `selectedItems` that should be provided in `useMemo` dependencies, you have other issue, which is that you don't modify your state really here `setSelectedItems(state)`

Arrays are being compared by reference, so if you have `const x = y = []`; and then `x.push('1')`, `x` is still equal to `y`. Hence when you do

```
let state = selectedItems
...
state.push(...)
...
setSelectedItems(state)
```

It doesn't trigger re-render cause `state` is still equals to previous one (to `selectedItems`)

The fix could be either

`state = [...state, item.id]` instead of `push`

Or `setSelectedItems([...state])`